# Transparency failure when creating a tabBarItem image for iOS in Inkscape

Tags: ios, transparency, inkscape

I am trying to create a tabBarItem image in Inkscape.  I drew a simple black icon in a 30 x 30 pixel inkscape file.  I saved as png and svg.  I assumed that the background would be transparent by default when I saved as png.  However, when I bring it into Xcode and make it my tabBarItem, I get a solid white square, indicating that the image is not transparent and the whole thing is being treated as black pixels.

How do I export it in greyscale with a transparent background so that I will get the expected appearance in iOS?

Thanks,

Dessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a discussion about transparent backgrounds in Inkscape here that may shed some light:

http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=1253